# AngularJS and ExtJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, extjs, extjs4, extjs6

I have a requirement to use extjs with angular. Could you please suggest how to achieve this :

- **Initialize extjs library in angular** I have used "bower install extjs" to inject library and library is downloaded. Would like to know more on how to use further in angular.
- **How to build interaction layer** between extjs angular, so that i will have angular controller to call extjs controller and so fort Or Pls suggest good communcation between these two libraries.
- **Project structure** : Would like to know on how my project structure looks like if I have these two library. Mainly for MVC structure.

Thanks